# Providing proxy to ssh command or putty via cmd in Windows

Tags: ssh, cmd, proxy, putty

I want to establish an SSH connection providing a proxy via command Line in Windows. While I use ssh command with ssh -o "ProxyCommand proxytunnel.exe ..." it gives me an error like

> CreateProcessW failed error:2
> posix_spawn: No such file or directory

Also with putty.exe command line I tried -proxycmd="proxytunnel.exe .." but this is giving error as well.

Any recommended way to establish an SSH connection providing a proxy via CMD?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `proxytunnel.exe` is not found. Specify this executable with full qualified file name which means with drive + path + name + extension enclosed in double quotes in case of file path contains a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. It is best to use always `"` around a file name as this is never wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Mofi, ssh -o "ProxyCommand proxytunnel.exe ..." is working for me now with full path.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax on a normal system is (but not on windows):

```
ssh user@myHost -p 4711 -oProxyCommand="ssh jumphost -W %h:%p"
```

or with proxytunnel

```
ssh user@myHost -p 4711 -oProxyCommand="proxytunnnel.exe args"
```

The comment from @MartinPrikryl reminds me of another problem.
The message `CreateProcessW failed error:2 posix_spawn: No such file or directory` is typical for a windows 10 system, because the ssh isn't able to find even ssh.exe itself in the ProxyCommand option.

You always need to specify the full path on windows, even the `.exe` is required.

```
ssh user@myHost -p 4711 -oProxyCommand="C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe jumphost -W %h:%p"
```

To use a full path in the .ssh/config file is possible (best with forward slashed), but leads to more problems, when you are using git-bash, then the ssh-agent breaks regulary.

Or better avoid to use the OpenSSH from windows at all and use always the ssh from git-bash, as this works much better and works also reliable with the ssh-agent (The ssh-agent from git-bash).
Then it's even possible to use vscode via a jumphost without headach.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You are right, I made an edit